# footer not showing in Angularjs app

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not sure why `<footer>` is not showing on the AngularJS app I'm building.

I use this code on index.html page

```
<footer class="page-footer"> 
    <div>
        <p>&copy; 2017 Company<span class="gap">-</span>All rights reserved</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.page-footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I tried your code in Codepen and it worked fine for me. Do you maybe have other CSS that is messing up your footer ?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi not far as I know but I will check again

Comment: Here is the [codepend](https://codepen.io/glouhaichi/pen/JrWdba).

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi Thank you I can see. But not sure why is not working Im now checking if my other css is the problems.

Comment: Check footer element shown in source code or when inspect element. if yes try adding a higher `z-index` value.

Comment: @Hareesh That's interesting point, thanks. When I checked the source code and inspect the page. The footer I created is not there but showing old footer I've deleted long time ago. How do removed this cache ??

Comment: Thanks alot for your help guy, I just realised I was using a wrong backup file rather than the central file on my server